avoiding __uint128_t in libc when cross compiling for 32-bit targets
I'm attempting to build a 32-bit toolchain in a docker container with an aarch64 architecture.  I have explicitly called --without-long-double-128 in my first pass of gcc but glibc is failing compile due to missing __uint128_t types.  I've looked through libc configuration options and I don't see a way to explicitly avoid these types.  Does anyone know a way around this?
First Error
1.504 /opt/usr/include/asm/sigcontext.h:81:9: error: unknown type name '__uint128_t'; did you mean '__uint32_t'?
1.504    81 |         __uint128_t vregs[32];
1.504       |         ^~~~~~~~~~~
1.504       |         __uint32_t
1.514 In file included from ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/powerpc/sys/user.h:24,
1.514                  from ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/sys/procfs.h:35,
1.514                  from ../sysdeps/nptl/thread_db.h:28,
1.514                  from ../nptl/descr.h:31:

GCC first pass config
RUN mkdir -p ${WORKROOT}/src/gcc/build
WORKDIR ${WORKROOT}/src/gcc/build
RUN ../configure --prefix=${WORKROOT}/tools \
    --target=powerpc-linux-gnu \
    --with-sysroot=${WORKROOT} \
    --with-newlib \
    --without-headers \
    --enable-initfini-array \
    --enable-default-pie \
    --enable-default-ssp \
    --disable-nls \
    --disable-shared \
    --disable-multilib \
    --disable-decimal-float \
    --disable-threads \
    --disable-libatomic \
    --disable-libgomp \
    --disable-libquadmath \
    --disable-libssp \
    --disable-libvtv \
    --disable-libstdcxx \
    --disable-gcov \
    --without-long-double-128 \
    --enable-languages=c,c++

glibc config
RUN ../configure \
    --prefix=/usr \
    --host=powerpc-linux-gnu \
    --build=$(../scripts/config.guess) \
    --enable-kernel=4.14 \
    --with-headers=${WORKROOT}/usr/include \
    libc_cv_slibdir=/usr/lib

